# Is there a way to force an iteration of a loop to stop and move to the next one in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, break

Currently, I'm trying:

```
for address in master_locations:
    try:
        search = geocoder.get(address)

    except ValueError:
        coordinates.append(['0', '0'])
        break 

    xyz....
```

Basically, if I want the entire iteration of the loop to stop. If there's an error, it currently "stops" by finishing up the try/except argument and going on to "xyz". How can I get it to stop and go to the next iteration of the loop WITHOUT going to xyz?

Comment: Yes: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
for address in master_locations:
    try:
        search = geocoder.get(address)

    except ValueError:
        coordinates.append(['0', '0'])
        continue

    ... ect ....
```

If the `continue` statement is reached, the all code following it, ie the stuff thats in   `... ect ...`, will be skipped and the for loop will move on to the next address. Then the whole process will start again.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`continue` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) to skip to the next iteration of a loop.

`continue` skips the rest of the body of the loop:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print(i)
...     if i < 3:
...         continue
...     print('i is 3 or higher')
... 
0
1
2
3
i is 3 or higher
4
i is 3 or higher
```